# What do new users see when their question has close votes

Tags: support, new-users, privileges

I voted to close [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/230207/what-are-some-good-resources-on-text-formatting-algorithms), and then the OP asked for downvoters to give a comment.  Which made me wonder: what do new (low rep) users see when there is a close vote on their question (before it has been closed)?  I know that as someone with the right to vote, I could see what the votes are simply by starting the process of voting to close on my own question, but would that be necessary?

Comment: Are you talking about close-votes or down-votes here? Users see down-votes very clearly as a negative number to the left of their question. I don't think you see close votes unless you have that privilege.

Comment: I was talking about close votes.  I agree that downvotes for questions aren't really that useful for questions.  Close votes I had always assumed were visible to the asker.  If they aren't, then I agree that they don't do anything for the asker until the question is actually closed.

Comment: Can you edit the question to make it clear that's what you're talking about.

Comment: @ChrisF I think you can see close votes on your own question without having 3k.

Comment: @YannisRizos - You need a reputation score of 250 - http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes - I always forget.

Comment: (for the sake of completeness) when vote cast is on dupe, they see generated suggested dupe notice

Answer (score 1):

Below 250 rep, the user doesn't see anything related to close votes unless a higher rep user tells them.

See: [view close votes privileges](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes)

> This privilege allows you to view and cast close and reopen votes on your own questions.

---

And as gnat pointed out, they will see the comment of a suggested duplicate after the first duplicate vote is cast.